# Android-like text field in Qt using stylesheets

Tags: android, c++, css, qt

I would like to create a custom QLineEdit with an Android style such as:

[image]

I do not want to subclass and override the paint method, I do want to do it using Qt stylesheets. The goal is to paint the three blue lines of the text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're alright with using an image you could use a 'border-image' style and leave the top 6 slices blank/transparent.

Comment: I cannot use an image since the width is variable. I do need to implement this using stylesheets.